# How to print native query into console?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am creating web-app to database management. One of functionalities is "interpreter SQL".
Here is my code which is used to execute queries:

**Example 1**

```
1  public String executeSQL(String[] split){
2      SessionFactory hibernateFactory = someService.getHibernateFactory();
3      Session session = hibernateFactory.openSession();
4      String message = null;
5      for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
6          try{
7              String query = split[i];
8              session.doWork(connection -> connection.prepareStatement(query).execute());
9      
10             message = "Success!";
11         }
12         catch(Exception e){
13             message = ((SQLGrammarException) e).getSQLException().getMessage();
14         }
15      
16      }
17      session.close();
18      return message;
19  }
```

**Can someone tell me how to call "getResultList()"*(line 8)*?**
I know how to do this in that example (with createNativeQuery):

**Example 2**

```
1  public String executeSQL(String[] split){
2      SessionFactory hibernateFactory = someService.getHibernateFactory();
3      Session session = hibernateFactory.openSession();
4      String message = null;
5      for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
6          try{
7              String query = split[i];
8              EntityManager entityManager = hibernateFactory.createEntityManager();
9              List<Object[]> resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
10             resultList.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
11             message = "Success!";
12          }
13         catch(Exception e){
14              // i can't catch SQLException here :( i mean i don't know how...
15         }
16  
17      }
18      session.close();
19      return message;
20  }
```

but as you can see *(line 14)* I don't know how to catch SQLException here because instead of SQLException I am getting this:
[image]
and i am not able to get access to that field to get the message (it is private):
[image]
I need that message to print it into my html. So i am trying another method to execute queries prepareStatement().
**Anyone have an idea how to print that query into console *(Example 1)*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your SQL queries printed into your console, add the following to your **application.properties** file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works thanks, but is there any way to get that "values" to some list in java? https://imgur.com/gzF151p

Comment: I believe you need to user a logger, but unfortunately I don`t know how. Look perhaps here: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot